# How to create a file inside a repository using PyGithub?

Tags: python, git, pygithub

As the documentation suggests, calling `create_file` on a `github.Repository.Repository` object should create a file but I am getting `github.GithubException.UnknownObjectException`.

My code is like this:

```
`repo.create_file('filename', 'commitmessage', 'content')`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with the authentication? Are you creating the file in a directory that exists?

Comment: @J.P.Petersen I have authenticated and downloading a file, accessing a repo, etc. work fine.

Comment: Does the user have rights to write?

Comment: @J.P.Petersen Yes. Could you please try it out yourself and send me the code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to start the filename with a slash `/`. I've tried the following command, and it worked:

```
In [12]: repo.create_file('/filename', 'commitmessage', 'content')
Out[12]:
{'commit': Commit(sha="201e0e5b91f7ec431d5b06cc47affff202e3de04"),
 'content': ContentFile(path="filename")}
```

Answer (score 0):

more detailed answer:

**1. auth to github using a [PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.9/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens#creating-a-personal-access-token) that you generate:**

```py
def auth_github():

    if "GITHUB_TOKEN" not in os.environ:
        raise ValueError("GITHUB_TOKEN not found")
    
    auth = Auth.Token(os.environ["GITHUB_TOKEN"])
    if "GITHUB_HOST" not in os.environ:
        raise ValueError("GITHUB_HOST not found")

    baseUrl="https://"+os.environ["GITHUB_HOST"]+"/api/v3"
    #print(baseUrl)

    g = Github(auth=auth, base_url=baseUrl)

    return g
```

here i'm using env variable that will inject before executing python code .

**2. get your repo**

```py
def get_repo():
    """
    Get the repository object
    """
    g=auth_github()
    if "GITHUB_REPO" not in os.environ:
        raise ValueError("GITHUB_REPO not found")
    return g.get_repo(os.environ["GITHUB_REPO"])
```

same as 1., i will use env variable to get the repo name that i want to push into

**3. create your file and push it**

```py
def create_file(filePath,fileName,content,message="",branch="main")-> dict[str, ContentFile | Commit]:
    """
    Create a file in the repo
    """
    repo=get_repo()
    if message=="":
        message="adding "+fileName+" file"
    return repo.create_file(path=filePath+fileName,message=message,content=content,branch=branch)
```

`filePath,fileName,content` have `str` type

if you need more details on how you get an existing file, deleting file etc, go to [pygithub doc](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html)